# Initilizing a class's static data member

Tags: c++, static

I'm trying to learn C++ and have encountered a concept that I can't wrap my head around. I have defined a class with a static data member in a header file and am trying to initialize it in a separate CPP file. In order for the for this to work, I have to specify that same data member's type again, which seems really weird, like defining a variable with the same name and type again. I would like to know why I have to specify the variable's type again.

I'm including the code(I'm also using the SFML framework):

Header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TEXTURE_HOLDER_H
#define TEXTURE_HOLDER_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <map>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
class TextureHolder
{
private:
    // A map container from the STL,
    // that holds related pairs of String and Texture
    map<string, Texture> m_Textures;
    // A pointer of the same type as the class itself
    // the one and only instance
    static TextureHolder* m_s_Instance;
public:
    TextureHolder();
    static Texture& GetTexture(string const& filename);
};
#endif // !TEXTURE_HOLDER_H
```

CPP file:

```
#include "TextureHolder.h"

// Include the "assert feature"
#include <assert.h>

TextureHolder* TextureHolder::m_s_Instance = nullptr;
.
.
.
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: It's the language rules that you do that. Alternatively you can specify it as inline and initialize it inside the class.

Comment: It just forward declaration in the class and defitinition+initialization in cpp. The same is done for methods.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I'll read more about forward-declaration.

Comment: For those interested, read more about forward-declaration.

Comment: You have both traditional header guards and `#pragma once`. Just pick one; there is no reason to use both.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You have to specify the type second type because that how C++ is designed.
There is no syntax sugar for that, AFAIK.

A partial workaround is to create a shorter name for the type (`typedef`/`using`) if it gets too long.

### Long answer

Static variables inside a class definition are declarations. It is for a reason - if compiler would create the variable in every compilation unit you include your header to, the linker wouldn't be able to tell which one to use. That's why you have to define the variable manually, in only one compilation unit. C++ is pretty low-level language in that regard. (Maybe incoming feature of modules will change that but I don't know much about them so it's just a guess.)

The problem is that declaration in C++ is a secondary concept to definition. Declaration just tells the compiler that declaration exists somewhere, even if it is a different file. Classes are quite unique in the regard that declaration seems to be more important than definition. From the point of view of the language structure, it would be pretty backward if you have to tell the type while declaring variable and not while defining it. I personally think that there still could be some syntactic sugar, like option to use keyword `auto` instead of full type but for now we have to enjoy what we have.